# Deploying Software to macOS Endpoints with Command Line Arguments

Tags: macos, software-distribution, installation-package

I have a macho executable for some software that can be installed from the command line by executing `installer -unique_key ABC123`

I'm trying to package the executable up with the command line arguments so that when it is executed, it will install with the command line arguments.

My goal is to have the software install by simply executing the file without having to supply the command line arguments manually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `pkgbuild` on the command line, you can archive the mach-o executable in a package, along with scripts to call the mach-o with the command line args.

For example,

```
pkgbuild --root ./bom --scripts ./scripts --version 0.1 --identifier com.companyname.myapp myArchive.pkg
```

The `--root` takes a path to a folder called bom, in which you can layout the folder structure of where your mach-o will be deployed. For example, you could have

```
./bom/Applications/myMach-O.app
```

Installing would copy the myMach-O.app bundle to `/Applications`

`--scripts` is the path to a folder containing scripts. You can use a `preinstall` script to be called before deployment, or `postinstall` for after deployment. Therefore, you'd want to use `postinstall` to call your mach-o executable with the required arguments.

`--version` is the version of the package

`--identifier` is a unique identifier for the package.

The final argument to `pkgbuild` is package output path.

You can refer to the man pages for `pkgbuild` for more detailed info and options to building packages.